# Ubuntu (store version) - path for console emulators

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've currently moved from old WSL which was called `Bash` to `Ubuntu` from windows store. I'm using it along with ConEmu terminal emulator. To configure this two together, I need to specify `ubuntu.exe` path in conemu, but I can't find it, do you know where's it installed ? For instance, before it was `C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe`

Comment: Path: `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1604.2017.922.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc`

Answer (score 0):

> Execute `where ubuntu` command in cmd to find correct path.

for example:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe`